# CRF Loss implementation for Semantic Segmentation

Tags: tensorflow, conv-neural-network, loss-function, crf

I would like to implement the CRF Loss in TensorFlow. 
Say that my code looks like the following:

```
# input to the model and ground truth segmentation mask
image = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, N, M, 1])
gt_mask = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, N, M, n_classes])

# prediction:
pred_mask = my_cnn(image)
pred_mask = tf.nn.softmax(pred_mask)  # has shape = [None, N, M, n_classes]

# compute CRF loss 
crf_loss = ... ?
```

In particular, the `crf_loss` formulation must be differentiable, so that I can use SGD to train the model.

I found [this](http://openaccess.thecvf.com/content_ECCV_2018/papers/Meng_Tang_On_Regularized_Losses_ECCV_2018_paper.pdf) paper saying that we can use the quadratic relaxation of the Potts model (equation 4, page 4). Any idea on how to implement all of this in TensorFlow in my example?

Thank you for your help :)

Comment: I believe this an existing implementation in TF: https://github.com/psycharo/tf-densecrf

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I found a nice implementation in TensorFlow of what I was looking for. I will post it in the answers so that everybody can have access to it :)

Answer (score 1):

Delving more in the literature, I found that CRF is usually implemented in fully convolutional networks as an RNN, as suggested in the very nice [ICCV 2015 paper](http://www.robots.ox.ac.uk/~szheng/papers/CRFasRNN.pdf) from Zheng et al.

They also shared an implementation [here](https://github.com/sadeepj/crfasrnn_keras), while another implementation (that should be more flexible) has been shared [here](https://github.com/MiguelMonteiro/CRFasRNNLayer).

@Jindřich pointed out that there should be some useful code [here](https://github.com/psycharo/tf-densecrf), too.